# How to store and use sensitive data in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, redux, local-storage

I am doing a Website 100% in ReactJS, It's a simple/medium complex, this has a Login, Profile and other sections more. After Users Log into the site the login callback returns some important values like: "Token, UserRole". Currently I'm storing these values in Web client using **localStorage** .

**My doubt is the next:** There is a better way to store this values? Because if any person changes the value from the Browser Console this could be a BIG ISSUE because they could change the role and then execute things that they never should do.

I thought to do it with Redux, but if the users Refresh the website then they lost the values, so I am not pretty sure to choose this.

What do you think guys?

TIA!

Comment: The most secure way I know of is to use the JWT approach (something encrypted containing claims about the user that only the server can decrypt) im combination with a http-only cookie that can't be accessed by any JS. It can't be modified by the user since they don't have the private key. The server only accepts what it has encrypted itself before.

Answer (score 3):

The general rule is to never trust any data stored client-side, except for an authentication token or the equivalent. All changes that the user makes that involves the server should be verified on the server. So, rather than:

> if any person changes the value from the Browser Console this could be a BIG ISSUE because they could change the role and then execute things that they never should do

Instead, the right thing to do would be, when the client wants to do something (such as edit their profile), have the client send their authentication token (or session ID) with the rest of the payload to your server. Have your server examine the token, check that the user associated with the token actually does have the required permissions for what they want to do, and only then continue to process the request.

Whether you also happen to store some information in Redux or elsewhere has no impact.

Storing login-related information client-side is relatively common and isn't inherently bad - just make sure to always verify it on the server when something that requires permissions is requested.

One approach some use is for the server to create an encrypted JWT that only the server can decode, which gets sent with requests.

Comment: I would go further and remove the “except for” clause in the “never trust” advice: always verify _everything_.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree with you and I believe the same that you "The server must validate everything ALWAYS" it does not matter if somebody change the user role from the browser, because when the app hit to the server this will return some kind of error. Dont you?

Comment: @jsejcksn The reason I'd like to trust the auth token or equivalent is because I'm not happy with the UI implications of the alternative, of re-authorizing with a password or something every time the user makes a request (that requires privileges) to the server. It's somewhat more secure (what if someone else hops into the user's seat while they're in the bathroom?) but much more inconvenient IMO.

Comment: @JuanAndres I think it'd be more like - the user role isn't communicated from the client to the server at all. Rather, when the client makes a request, the server will look up their role and respond to the client if they don't have the right permissions.

Comment: weell, I understand your point @CertainPerformance but my question was because depending on the user role then the application would show certain pages or not, for that reason was my question, If I store the role in a Cookie or LocalStorage then any user could change the role and would show them that page. I changed the code and I am not using localStorage for that, I updated for Redux implementation now is in the State of the application.